# Making a UIView landscape

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiimageview, uiinterfaceorientation

I have created an iPhone app, which is a tab bar application and only in portrait orientation.
From one tab  I am presenting a modal view which contain `UIImage` view.

Can I make landscape orientation only to that view while rotating iPhone to 90 degree?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes , you can.

There are a few settings, code part which need to make it.

Depends also for which version, hopefully aren't targeting all supported by xcode, because it is horrible. Better choose only one, like the lastest iOS.